# Add link in a table Angular 8

Tags: angular, html-table, hyperlink, download, primeng

I have a table with some columns and I have a "documents" column that can be clicked and downloaded.
How can I ONLY make the document name a link?

**HTML**

```
<p-table #dt3 [columns]="colsPermessi" [value]="permessi" [paginator]="true" [scrollable]="false" [rows]="10" [autoLayout]="true">

<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pResizableColumn>{{col.header}} </th>
       <th>Azioni</th>
       <th>Permessi</th>
    </tr>
 </ng-template>

  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
     <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
         <td *ngFor="let col of colsPermessi">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
         </td>
     </tr>
  </ng-template>
```

[image]

I therefore want the "document" column to be clickable and on click it calls the "downloadFile ()" function.
How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hppdk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using *ngIf to separate your cases. For documento columns, use the ngIf to insert a hyperlink tag. For all else, just insert the text. See the example below:

```
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
     <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
         <td *ngFor="let col of colsPermessi">
            <span *ngIf="col.header == 'Documento'><a [href]="col.url">{{rowData[col.field]}}</a></span>
            <span *ngIf="col.header != 'Documento'>{{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
         </td>
     </tr>
  </ng-template>
```